# I deleted the portal to the end city in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was messing around with my Minecraft world and accidentally deleted the portal on the main end island that leads to the first end city (don't ask me how)

[image: End portal gone]

Does anyone know how I can put it back? Or do I have to complete a new Ender Dragon fight?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **can** beat the ender dragon **again** to spawn a **new**, different end gateway, yes.
**Alternatively**, you can use `/setblock` to create one in the place of the old one, as explained below.

From the [wiki page:](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_Gateway_(block)#Usage)

- The `ExitPortal` tag holds a set of X/Y/Z coordinates to determine the general location the player can be "safely" teleported to when entering.
- Setting `ExactTeleport` to 1 teleports entities to the specified coordinates exactly instead of at a safer location around those coordinates.

Example:

```
/setblock ~ ~-2 ~ minecraft:end_gateway{ExactTeleport:0,ExitPortal:{X:1000,Y:90,Z:3000}} replace
```

This will create an end gateway 2 blocks underneath you that exits at `1000 90 3000`.

Comment: You can also simply bridge out, but I wouldn't recommend it since it is at *minimum* 1000 blocks in any direction

Comment: @AMJ does coming back through the 1k+ gateway generate a new gateway block at the coordinates of the old one on the main island?